# How Spring WebClient work inside and reason of ReadTimeoutException

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, reactive-programming, spring-webclient

I have a Spring WebClient which built by method:

```
public static WebClient build(ReactorResourceFactory factory) {
        final ConnectionProvider fixedPool = ConnectionProvider
            .builder("CustomClient")
            .maxConnections(1000)
            .pendingAcquireMaxCount(-1) // keep the backwards compatibility
            .pendingAcquireTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(1000))
            .maxIdleTime(Duration.ofSeconds(5))
            .maxLifeTime(Duration.ofHours(1))
            .build();
        final LoopResources loop = LoopResources.create("CustomClient", 1, 4, true);
        factory.setUseGlobalResources(false);
        factory.setConnectionProvider(fixedPool);
        factory.setLoopResources(loop);
        Function<? super TcpClient, ? extends TcpClient> finalMapper = tcp -> tcp
            .doOnConnected(conn -> conn
                .addHandlerLast(new ReadTimeoutHandler(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS))
                .addHandlerLast(new WriteTimeoutHandler(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                ))
            .option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, 1500));
        Function<HttpClient, HttpClient> mapper = c -> c.tcpConfiguration(finalMapper)
            .compress(true)
            .keepAlive(true)
            .disableRetry(true);
        ClientHttpConnector connector = new ReactorClientHttpConnector(factory, mapper);
        return WebClient.builder().clientConnector(connector).build();
    }
```

Sometimes this client produce ReadTimeoutException even if other side send successful response. This most often occurs when the serviceA makes a large number of calls simultaneously (30-50 requests within 10-50ms). As a result, in the logs I observe the following situation (ServiceA do request to ServiceB):

ServiceA

```
Oct 24, 2023 @ 12:16:08.946 INFO request in 0.585 secs
Oct 24, 2023 @ 12:16:08.939 [CustomClient-epoll-3] WARN reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientConnect ||  >> [0eac89ee-1, L:/<ip>:56790 - R:<host>/<ip>:443] The connection observed an error
Oct 24, 2023 @ 12:16:08.939 io.netty.handler.timeout.ReadTimeoutException: null
```

ServiceB

```
Oct 24, 2023 @ 12:16:08.568 INFO Last successful response to ServiceA
```

As I understand ServiceB sucessfully handled all requests, but WebClient in ServiceA for some reason didn't process the responses and throw ReadTimeoutException.

Questions:

1. How Spring WebClient works under the hood? What happens when we call `retrive()` and at what point in time does the countdown for ReadTimeoutException begin?
2. How to fix this problem? Did timeout throw due to lack of threads in LoopResources or what?