# Spring Boot WebClient issue while upgrade from Spring Boot version 3.1.7 to 3.2.2

Tags: spring, spring-boot, project-reactor

Our team is using the WebClient from Spring for interacting with API's. After upgrading the Spring dependencies from version 3.1.7 to 3.2.1 we got the following error:

java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Did not observe any item or terminal signal within 240000ms in 'peekTerminal' (and no fallback has been configured)

This causes the application to stop working normally.

The configuration of the WebClient bean:

```
@Bean()
WebClient webClient() {
    return WebClient
        .builder()
            .clientConnector(
                new ReactorClientHttpConnector(
                    HttpClient
                        .create()
                        .wiretap(true)
                )
            )
        .baseUrl("API URL")
        .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON.toString())
        .build();
    }
```

Implementation of the WebClient:

```
webClient
    .method(HttpMethod.POST)
    .bodyValue([POJO class])
    .retrieve()
    .bodyToMono([POJO class])
    .doOnError(exception -> log the exceptioin)
    .doOnSuccess(response-> process the response)
    .timeout(Duration.ofMinutes(4))
    .block();
```

I would expect the upgrade from 3.1.7 to 3.2.1 didn't break the implementation of the WebClient. The API we access has not been changed nor has the other code in our application that implements the WebClient.

We have checked the release notes on https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/releases/tag/v3.2.1 but couldn't find a cause to this issue.

Maven pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>a</groupId>
    <artifactId>b</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.release>21</java.release>
        <spring-boot.version>3.2.2</spring-boot.version>
        <maven-clean-plugin.version>3.3.1</maven-clean-plugin.version>
        <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.11.0</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
        <maven-deploy-plugin.version>3.1.1</maven-deploy-plugin.version>
        <maven-failsafe-plugin.version>3.1.2</maven-failsafe-plugin.version>
        <maven-install-plugin.version>3.1.1</maven-install-plugin.version>
        <maven-resources-plugin.version>3.3.1</maven-resources-plugin.version>
        <maven-surefire-plugin.version>3.1.2</maven-surefire-plugin.version>
        <maven-verifier-plugin.version>1.1</maven-verifier-plugin.version>
        <maven-source-plugin.version>3.3.0</maven-source-plugin.version>
        <maven-dependency-plugin.version>3.6.0</maven-dependency-plugin.version>
        <maven-enforcer-plugin.version>3.4.1</maven-enforcer-plugin.version>
        <dependency-check-maven.version>8.4.0</dependency-check-maven.version>
        <versions-maven-plugin.version>2.16.1</versions-maven-plugin.version>
        <springdoc.version>2.3.0</springdoc.version>        
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
            <version>${springdoc.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>       
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven-clean-plugin.version}</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven-dependency-plugin.version}</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven-enforcer-plugin.version}</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven-failsafe-plugin.version}</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven-resources-plugin.version}</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven-install-plugin.version}</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven-source-plugin.version}</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-verifier-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven-verifier-plugin.version}</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.owasp</groupId>
                    <artifactId>dependency-check-maven</artifactId>
                    <version>${dependency-check-maven.version}</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${versions-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <release>${java.release}</release>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>A</mainClass>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.owasp</groupId>
                <artifactId>dependency-check-maven</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <failBuildOnCVSS>10</failBuildOnCVSS>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>check</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>enforce-java</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>enforce</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <rules>
                                <requireJavaVersion>
                                    <version>[21,)</version>
                                </requireJavaVersion>
                            </rules>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>enforce-maven</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>enforce</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <rules>
                                <requireMavenVersion>
                                    <version>[3.6.3,)</version>
                                </requireMavenVersion>
                            </rules>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>no-duplicate-declared-dependencies</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>enforce</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <rules>
                                <banDuplicatePomDependencyVersions/>
                            </rules>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>            
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Help to resolve this issue would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you share your build file, showing versions of all the dependencies you're using (especially Spring Framework and Reactor)?

Comment: I've updated the ticket to show the content of the pom.xml file.

Comment: Seems to be related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77351287/how-spring-webclient-work-inside-and-reason-of-readtimeoutexception

Comment: FYI... our solution has been solved. We are running an APM agent version which couldn't handle the reactive nature of the WebClient from Spring. An upgrade of the agent solved our issue.